# How to watch\subscribe to event in Azure account

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Is there a way to watch\subscribe to events using the Azure API for changes to VM instances?
For example if someone adds a tag to an asset (or changes any type of property) I want to get a trigger via the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Event Grid is an eventing system built into Azure. It should handle what you are looking for.

[Azure Event Grid documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/?WT.mc_id=none-stackoverflow-nepeters)

Comment: I've seen this in my searches not the most optimal solution for my use case but I guess this will have to make do..

Answer (score 0):

I guess that it should be possible with [Activity Logs and Alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-activity-log-alerts-new-experience)

Comment: I don't want to create an additional log repo but get the events via API on the fly and make decisions, I don't need to keep the data

Answer (score 0):

Use Azure logic apps to set the desired condition for trigger and fire an email as trigger.

Comment: I don't want to use another service but just watch the event on have my own logic.